# Parse Instant without second

Tags: java, time

I have date in string `"2015-05-08T02:56"`. As you can see it doesn't have seconds.

When I try to parse it with:

```
Instant instant = Instant.from(
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm")
                .parse("2015-05-08T02:56"));
```

I get Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain Instant from TemporalAccessor: {MinuteOfHour=56, HourOfAmPm=2},ISO resolved to 2015-05-08 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.Instant.from(Instant.java:378)
    at sample.Main.main(Main.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: InstantSeconds
    at java.time.format.Parsed.getLong(Parsed.java:203)
    at java.time.Instant.from(Instant.java:373)
    ... 6 more
```

How to parse this date correctly and fill seconds with `0`?

Comment: Change pattern to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"`, with `HH` in uppercase.

Comment: @Andreas, why is it refusing the AM/PM format in `Instant.from(TemporalAccessor)`

Comment: @AxelH Because `hh` (01-12) without `a` (AM/PM) is an incomplete hour value. Input `02:00` can be 2 AM or 2 PM. To correctly parse hour of day, you need either `HH`, or `hh` + `a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I forgot to specify timezone

```
Instant instant = Instant.from(
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
                .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
                .parse("2015-05-08T22:57"));
```

works fine.

**UPDATE:** Also I had another problem I used `hh` instead of `HH`.

Comment: *and* you changed the `hh` to uppercase. You need **both** timezone and uppercase hours for this code to work.

Comment: @Freeman He is correctly answering his own question which is a totally valid thing to do.

Comment: @Michael Yes. I will note it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A more flexible way:

```
var instant = ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.parse("2015-05-08T22:57", LocalDateTime::from)
                .toInstant(UTC);
```